# Create AWS Parameter Store key/value pair with powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-parameter-store

Is there a way to create a new secure Key/Value pair on AWS Parameter store with Powershell ? Is the only workaround to use AWSCLI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Create a Systems Manager parameter (Tools for Windows PowerShell) - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/param-create-ps.html#param-create-ps-securestring):

```
Write-SSMParameter `
    -Name "parameter-name" `
    -Value "parameter-value" `
    -Type "SecureString"  `
    -KeyId "a KMS CMK ID, a KMS CMK ARN, an alias name, or an alias ARN"
```

See also: [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store using Powershell](https://medium.com/@ripon.banik/aws-systems-manager-parameter-store-using-powershell-aa44935e52b5)